# How to create a script to run several scripts on different servers

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I need to automate the execution of several scripts, and I'm writing a script.

The scripts have to run concurrently because they are part of a benchmarking suite.

I'm trying to execute 6 different scripts on two different machines through the following script:

```
!/bin/bash

(cd /opt/scripts
sudo sh runp.sh)

(cd /opt/scripts
sudo sh runt.sh)

(cd /opt/scripts
sudo sh rund.sh)

(echo "iniciando slave remoto"
ssh sut@slave <<'ENDSSH'
cd /opt/scripts
sudo sh runs.sh
ENDSSH)

(ssh sut@slave <<'ENDSSH'
/home/sut/pf/server-sysfs 8989
ENDSSH)

(cd /opt/scripts
sudo sh runc.sh)
```

but it blocks on the 3rd script and the echo message doesn't show on screen.

Any hint or help on how can I approach it will be very appreciated.

P.S. I have 0 bash scripting experience, so maybe my approach isn't even remotely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo sh /opt/scripts/runp.sh &
sudo sh /opt/scripts/runt.sh &
sudo sh /opt/scripts/rund.sh &

ssh sut@slave sudo sh /opt/scripts/runs.sh &
ssh sut@slave /home/sut/pf/server-sysfs 8989 &

sudo sh /opt/scripts/runc.sh &
```

Comment: Thank you @jherran for your answer but it appears as if the ssh scripts weren't runing.

Comment: If you can connect with `ssh sut@slave`, should do. Anyway, you could append `nohup` before the first `ssh` command and run again. This will generate a file called `nohup.out` that you must check to see the results of the command. Do not append nohup to both ssh command, because last one overwrite the output of first one.

Comment: your solution "works" in theory, but the scripts execute programs that make extensive use of working directory and that's becoming a pain in the ass.

Comment: You want an script to run six parallels process and you got it. If the six scripts executed by this script make extensive use of working directory, that another problem I suppose, and you have to look after it or ask another question.

Comment: Thank you again, I finally got it working mixing your answer with the parenthesis thing.